# why do i get Error in NetBeans Installation

Tags: netbeans

I did the following

**Step 01:**

```
wget -c https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/netbeans/netbeans/11.2/Apache-NetBeans-11.2-bin-linux-x64.sh
```

**Step 02:**

```
chmod +x Apache-NetBeans-11.2-bin-linux-x64.sh
```

**Step 03 :**

```
./Apache-NetBeans-11.2-bin-linux-x64.sh
```

Error:

> ./Apache-NetBeans-11.2-bin-linux-x64.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' 
>   ./Apache-NetBeans-11.2-bin-linux-x64.sh: line 1: <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Apparently wget downloaded the html page, not the actual shell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are downloading the website where you can choose a mirror to download NetBeans and try to execute that.

Try instead

> wget -c
>   http://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/apache/netbeans/netbeans/11.2/Apache-NetBeans-11.2-bin-linux-x64.sh

or any other mirror and repeat your steps.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the update ..I downloaded it from the mirror

Comment: Netbeans 12.4 on Fedora 34 and same issue. Tryed to download from many mirrors, and still appears same message... Tryed to install with sudo and with the curretn user. Same result..  TIA.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused because you are downloading the apache website HTML, when you open your URL you'll find the real script link:

Website: https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/netbeans/netbeans-installers/14/Apache-NetBeans-14-bin-linux-x64.sh

Script: https://dlcdn.apache.org/netbeans/netbeans-installers/14/Apache-NetBeans-14-bin-linux-x64.sh